# Big-O time complexity of 4sum problem. Brute force approach

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set, time-complexity

I am doing this problem called 4sum. [Link to problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/).

> Given an array of n numbers and an integer(this is the target
> element). Calculate the total number of quads (collection of 4
> distinct numbers chosen from these n numbers) are there for which the
> sum of quad elements will add up to the target element.

I wrote this code for brute force approach. According to me the big-o time complexity comes out to be ---  n^4 log (n^4). I have given the reason below. Although the complexity should be n^4 only. Please help me understand what am i missing.

```
set<vector<int>>s;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
            for(int l = k + 1; l < n; l++) {
                if (a[i]+a[j]+a[k]+a[l]==target) {
                    s.insert({a[i], a[j], a[k], a[l]});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logic is to generate all possible quads (with distinct elements), then for each quad check whether the sum of quad elements is equal to the target or not. If yes, then insert the quad in the set.

Now, we cannot know how many quads will match this condition because this solely depends on input. But to get the upper bound we assume that every quad that we check satisfies the condition. Hence, there are a total of N^4 insertions in the set.
For N^4 insertions --- complexity is N^4 log(N^4).

Comment: Are you asking for a new algorithm w/ the lower complexity, or how you have mis-computed the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: I am asking why is complexity wrong. What mistake am i making while computing the complexity. thankyou for your time.

Comment: What makes you think your complexity is wrong?

Comment: an expert told me it should be O(n^4). He can be wrong. Please give your opinion.

Comment: Actually the quads have to be unique. For that reason I used set to avoid duplicates.

Comment: The expert is assuming that the processing for each quad is O(1). That would be true if you were A) printing each quad, or B) adding the quads to a vector, or C) adding the quads to a hash table, or D) just counting the quads. Because you have chosen to add the quads to a set, you've increased the runtime. However, the distinction is that you've increased the **runtime of the implementation**, not the **complexity of the algorithm**. The algorithm is the method of selecting 4 indexes to create a quad. What you do with the quad once you've found it is not part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (a[i]+a[j]+a[k]+a[l]==target) {
    s.insert({a[i], a[j], a[k], a[l]});
  }
```

This gets executed `O(N^4)` times, indeed.

> to get the upper bound we assume that every quad that we check satisfies the condition.

Correct.

> For N^4 insertions --- complexity is N^4 log(N^4).

Not so, because `N^4` insertions do not necessarily result in a set with `N^4` elements.

The cost of an insertion is `O(log(s.size())`. But `s.size()` is upper-bound by the number of distinct ways `K` in which `target` can be expressed as a sum of 4 integers in a given range, so the worst case cost is `O(log(K))`. While `K` can be a large number, it does *not* depend on `N`, so as far as the complexity in `N` is concerned, this counts as constant time `O(1)`, and therefore the overall complexity is still `O(N^4)·O(1) = O(N^4)`.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Regarding @MysteriousUser's suggestion to use [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) instead of [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert), that would change the `O(1)` constant of the loop body to a better one, indeed, but would not change the overall complexity, which would still be `O(N^4)`.

The other option which *would* in fact increase the complexity to `O(N^4 log(N))` as proposed by the OP would be [`std::multi_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert), since in that case each insertion would result in a size increase of the multiset.